# Svelte libraries loaded without style

Tags: css, user-interface, svelte, sapper

I tried to connect the "Materialify" and "Carbon Components for Svelte" libraries to the `Sapper` project. But it turns out that the components are loaded, but without styles. What could be the problem? The code is shown below, installed using the commands listed on the official websites. Working on Ubuntu 20

```
<script>
    import {DataTable} from 'carbon-components-svelte'
</script>

<svelte:head>
    <title>Sapper project template</title>
</svelte:head>

<DataTable
    headers={[
            {key: 'name', value: 'Name'},
            {key: 'age', value: 'age'}
    ]}
    rows={[
            {id: 0, name: 'Stepan', age: 14},
            {id: 1, name: 'Maxim', age: 24}
    ]}
/>
```

Result:
[Compiled result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GKgq.png)

Comment: Did you use one of the templates as mentioned in the Usage / Scaffolding section (https://github.com/IBM/carbon-components-svelte#usage), and did you make sure it was the right template for your use case?

Comment: Thank you) 
I'm not very attentive, so I didn't see this) I looked at the connection not on GitHub, but on the library website (https://carbon-svelte.vercel.app)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [Thomas Hennes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5438616/thomas-hennes) for answer.

In order for the styles to work, you need to connect them according to the instructions in the GitHub repository of this library.
Solution for Sapper: in the _layout.svelte (routes) file, in the `script` tags, add:

```
import 'carbon-components-svelte/css/[here styles file].css'
```

Comment: I don't understand this. What import code do you put where to make white theme work with Carbon UI for Svelte?